# handler method in spring boot for post request is updating null values in database

Tags: java, spring-boot, api, rest, httphandler

I am trying to create a handler method in the controller class to handle post request with JSON in body to add the details coming in JSON to the database.

Handler method

```java
    // post method to add record in account table
    @PostMapping("/accounts")
    public ResponseEntity<Account> postAccount(@ModelAttribute Account account) {
        Account ac = this.accountServices.addAccount(account);

        return new ResponseEntity<>(ac, HttpStatus.OK);
    }
```

**addAccount()** method in **AccountServices** class

```java
  // add an account
    public Account addAccount(Account account) {
        Account acc = this.accountRepository.save(account);
        return acc;
    }
```

**AccountServices** interface extends **CrudRepository** interface.

```java
public interface AccountRepository extends CrudRepository<Account, Integer> {
//custom finder method to get book record with id
}
```

When I am sending HTTP request as shown below
[image]

I am getting below output in response in postman and database
[image]

In database only null values are added as shown in postman response.
I have no idea what is the error?
It should send the same object as response json.

Comment: Could you add your `Account` class as well, please?

Comment: Hi @thinkgruen, I used RequestBody instead of ModelAttribute in handler method and it is working properly. Thanks a lot for your comment.

Answer (score 1):

I used RequestBody instead of ModelAttribute in handler method and it is working properly.

```java
// post method to add record in account table
    @PostMapping("/accounts")
    public ResponseEntity<Account> postAccount(@RequestBody Account account) {
        System.out.println(account);
        Account ac = this.accountServices.addAccount(account);

        return new ResponseEntity<>(ac, HttpStatus.OK);
    }
```